# Count of pairs of disjoint subsets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I want to count the # of disjoint pairs $A, B \subseteq \{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$, s.t.

- $|A| = |B| = s$
- $a_1 < b_1$
- $a_k > b_k$ for some $k$

Here the elements of the set $A$ are $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_s$, similarly for $B$.

For example, all pairs for $n = 6, s = 3$ are:

$$
(\{1, 2, 6\}, \{3, 4, 5\})\\
(\{1, 3, 6\}, \{2, 4, 5\})\\
(\{1, 4, 5\}, \{2, 3, 6\})\\
(\{1, 4, 6\}, \{2, 3, 5\})\\
(\{1, 5, 6\}, \{2, 3, 4\})
$$

Through some coding and searching OEIS sequences for clues, I've found the following formula which seems to work:

$$\left( \frac{n!}{(n - 2 s) !s!s!} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{s + 1} \right) $$

Can anyone explain why/if this works (or if there's some simpler way to count this)?

Comment: $a_k > a_k$ for some $k$?

Comment: @BillyJoe Oops fixed.

Comment: @BillyJoe No, it's exact. I listed 5 pairs there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count as follows. Take $$\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{s}\binom{n-s}{s},$$
this is the ways to pick two disjoint sets and you give them an order based on the order of the first element, that is why you divide by $2.$ You know that the lowest element goes to $A.$ 
Now, you have to take care of the other condition. The negation of that is that $a_k<b_k$ for all $k.$ Pick $2s$ elements out of $n$ and consider the following construction every time that you pick an element for $B$ you have to have picked an element for $A$ this is the same as the combinatorial interpretation for **Catalan numbers** in the form of Dyck paths. Your formula becomes
$$\binom{n}{2s}C_s=\frac{1}{s+1}\binom{n}{2s}\binom{2s}{s}.$$
Take the difference because you are taking out these and you are done.